# sva:Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Tags: closures

I'm using sva function to remove the batch effect in a bind-targets

Two targets have been bound and the batch effect is GSE-number:

```
batch <- GSE2_targets$GSE
library(sva)
mod <-  model.matrix(~ as.factor(group), data= GSE2_targets)
GSE2_combat <- ComBat(dat = expr,
                   batch = batch,
                   par.prior = TRUE,
                   prior.plots = FALSE)
Error in as.vector(x, mode) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```